# Linux-friendly alternative to Meshroom on AMD system?

Tags: photography, 3d

I am running ArchLinux and Ubuntu on an AMD system. While I *really* like what Meshroom does, their main 3D reconstruction pipeline requires the use of an NVidea GPU. I found a supposed workaround online but it was really slow and didn't perform well compared to running the same example data because steps in the pipeline are skipped.